# What function superseded SpaceForm?

Tags: functions, export, grid-layouts, undocumented

In older versions of *Mathematica* you could use `SpaceForm` to leave a certain amount of spaces when writing to a file. For example, if we have the following data:

```
data = Table[{x, N[Exp[2 - x]]}, {x, 0, 40, 5}];
```

We can then write it to a file

```
MapThread[Write["file.txt", FortranForm[#], SpaceForm[4], FortranForm[#2]]&, Transpose[data]]
```

You can still use `SpaceForm` in the current version of *Mathematica* but it seems there is no documentation for it. I'm just wondering if that function was replaced by a newer one or how to do the same thing with a documented function.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: FWIW in v10 `SpaceForm[n]` puts *one* space regardless of the argument.  I cant find it documented for any old version either..

Comment: hmm it turns out `Print[1, SpaceForm[n], 2]` gives n spaces, but it doesn't work the same with `Write`

Comment: @george2079 I have checked the code in the question and it works as expected with *Mathematica* 10.4.1 on Win 7 x64: `SpaceForm[n]` writes exactly `n` spaces when used in `Write`.

Comment: there is some interaction with other formatting.. this `Write["file.txt", 0, SpaceForm[10], OutputForm[1]]` gives 10 spaces, while `Write["file.txt", 0, SpaceForm[10], 1]` gives just one.

Comment: @george2079 You are right, I have checked your example with versions 5.2 and 10.4.1 and got identical results: `Write["file.txt", 0, SpaceForm[10], 1]` writes just one space while `Write["file.txt", 0, SpaceForm[10], OutputForm[1]]` writes 10 spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1998/Jul/msg00330.html) MathGroup post the function `SpaceForm` was documented **only** via `Information` (i.e. the `SpaceForm::usage` [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html)) even in *Mathematica* 3.0. With current version 10.4.1 the situation is still the same:

```
? SpaceForm
```

> `SpaceForm[n]` prints as `n` spaces.

So you shouldn't worry: this function is in the current situation right from the start, nothing seems to be changed. It works as before and you can use it with the same confidence as earlier.

---

But if you need a solution based on well-documented functionality I recommend you instead of [buggy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113510/what-function-superseded-spaceform/115912#comment314722_113510) undocumented `SpaceForm[n]` use something like `StringJoin[Table[" ", {n}]]`, and switch from `Write` to `WriteString` since the latter writes in `OutputForm` what is convenient when you write a textual file:

```
str = OpenWrite[];
WriteString[str, 0, StringJoin[Table[" ", {10}]], FortranForm[4.658886145103398`*^-15], "\n"];
Close[str];
FilePrint[%]
```

> ```
> 0          4.658886145103398e-15
> ```

The following alternatives to `StringJoin[Table[" ", {n}]]` also work well:

```
StringJoin[ConstantArray[" ", n]]
StringJoin[Array[" " &, n]]
Nest[" " <> # &, "", n]
Row[Table[" ", {n}]]
```

With *Mathematica* 10.1 or higher you can use [`StringRepeat[" ", n]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRepeat.html) as a direct replacement of `SpaceForm[n]`:

```
str = OpenWrite[];
WriteString[str, 0, StringRepeat[" ", 10], FortranForm[4.658886145103398`*^-15], "\n"]
Close[str];
FilePrint[%]
```

> ```
> 0          4.658886145103398e-15
> ```

And finally you also can remedy `SpaceForm` as follows (for making the fix permanent you can add these lines into your Kernel [init.m](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html) file):

```
Unprotect[SpaceForm];
Format[SpaceForm[n_Integer], InputForm] := OutputForm[StringJoin[ConstantArray[" ", n]]];
Format[SpaceForm[n_Integer], OutputForm] := StringJoin[ConstantArray[" ", n]];
Protect[SpaceForm];
```

Now the [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113510/what-function-superseded-spaceform/115912?noredirect=1#comment314722_113510) is fixed:

```
Write["file.txt", 0, SpaceForm[10], 1]
FilePrint["file.txt"]
```

> ```
> 0          1
> ```

Comment: Have you seen [Spacer](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spacer.html)?

Comment: @yode `Spacer` doesn't fit the OP's needs because in `OutputForm` it isn't converted into the appropriate number of whitespace characters like `SpaceForm`: try `Spacer[3] // OutputForm` and compare to `{SpaceForm[3]} // OutputForm`.

Answer (score 3):

```
f = OpenWrite["test.txt"];
nsp[n_] := OutputForm[StringJoin[ConstantArray[" ", n]]]
Write[f, 1, nsp[3], 2, nsp[1], 3];
Close[f]
FilePrint["test.txt"]
```

> ```
> 1   2 3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
Export[
 "file.txt",
 Map[FortranForm, data, {2}],
 "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> "    "
]

(* File contents:
    0    7.38905609893065
    5    0.049787068367863944
    10    0.00033546262790251185
    15    2.2603294069810542e-6
    20    1.522997974471263e-8
    25    1.026187963170189e-10
    30    6.914400106940203e-13
    35    4.658886145103398e-15
    40    3.1391327920480296e-17
*)
```

Comment: `Export` will not be good enough for what I'm trying to do. I would like to use `Write` or `WriteString`

Comment: Why won't `Export` work for you in specific?

Comment: If for example I want to leave different number of spaces between different columns.